# Apex method to count most used words

Tags: apex

I have written the method below to find the most used words in a string. It seems a little long, maybe there's a better way to do this ?

```
 public String[] getMostUsed(){
    List<String> parts = text.split('\\s');
    Map<String,Integer> wordcounter = new Map<String,Integer>();
    Integer most = 0;
    List<String> themost = new List<String>();
    for(String s : parts){
        if(wordcounter.containsKey(s)){
            Integer i = wordcounter.get(s);
            wordcounter.put(s,++i);
        }else
            wordcounter.put(s,1);
    }
    for(Integer s : wordcounter.values()){
        if(s > most){
            most = s;
        }
    }
    for(String s : wordcounter.keySet()){
        if(wordcounter.get(s) == most){
            themost.add(s);
        }
    }
    return themost;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest using a `Comparable` here. You can then cache your map values and sort.

Here is what your wrapper would look like:

```
public class WordCounter implements Comparable
{
    final String word;
    Integer count;
    public WordCounter(String word)
    {
        this.word = word;
        this.count = 0;
    }
    public void increment() { count++; }
    public Integer compareTo(Object instance)
    {
        WordCounter that = (WordCounter)instance;
        return that.count - this.count;
    }
}
```

Then your algorithm would change to something like:

```
Map<String, WordCounter> counters = new Map<String, WordCounter>();
for (String word : words)
{
    if (!counters.containsKey(word))
        counters.put(word, new WordCounter(word));
    counters.get(word).increment();
}
List<WordCounter> sortedByCount = counters.values();
sortedByCount.sort();
String wordWithMaxCount = sortedByCount[0].word;
```